# Trying to install Joomla, can't get past first step (Configuration) never takes me to Database step

Tags: joomla

I've created database for Joomla and installed Joomla 3.9.5.  I visit the web installer and it shows the proper first page with the first step being the Configuration.  I enter the site name, email, username, password (twice), and hit Next.  The screen flashes the Joomla logo in the center and returns to the form at the same point.  It never proceeds to the Database step.

I've tried all kinds of suggestions and nothing works.  This server is already running another version of Joomla so I know the PHP/database/etc. is setup correctly.  I've also setup Joomla many times before but never had a problem.  I'm stuck :(

Comment: Do you have a htaccess in that folder?  If so, try removing.

Comment: No .htaccess in that folder.  In the web root folder there is an .htaccess file.  I also tried to delete it with the same results.

Comment: have you tried manually uploading the full joomla installation and overwriting the existing files?

Comment: I'm setting this site up for the first time, so yes, I manually uploaded the full Joomla installation.  There were no files to overwrite.  This website is on the same server as the other website, but a totally new server directory.

Comment: Can you check your browser inspector console and check errors ?

Comment: Can you increase the below values in your php.ini file            max_execution_time = 3000
max_file_uploads = 20000
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 14800M
post_max_size = 20000M
upload_max_filesize = 20000M

Comment: Please Increase the above values, will installed successfully

Comment: did you double check the folder permissions? may apache user can't access to that folder..

Answer (score 0):

There could be lots of reasons for this. It's good to share more info with the question, like, installation platform, web server name and version, mysql database version etc. My understanding from comments and the question body, it seems it could be the following case that mostly faced for installation. Joomla needs more power to process installation script than run a joomla instance.

Please increase the following value in your php.ini, restart web server and try again

max_execution_time =  3000

And

memory_limit = 256M

Hope helps